# Sending form errors back to view via redirect

Tags: cakephp

I recently started picking up on CakePHP and now I'm trying to build a contact form for my site.
It seems to work in validating the forms, but there's something I want to do now.
I want it to show any errors that occur (like missing a required field).
However, I want it to show 2 different possible states:
- A user error (user forgot a field or the field doesn't meet the requirements), show this below the field (using Bootstrap 4)
- A server error (mail couldn't send from the server - for example, the SMTP server is down), shown using the `Flash`

I've been searching far and wide for this, but I couldn't get any further on this without posting a question myself.
Below is all the code that I'm using  (running CakePHP 3.6)

src/Template/Pages/contact.ctp (controlled by the `PagesController`):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row no-banner">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>Contact Form</h4>
        <div style="padding-bottom:25px;">
          Got a question? we'd love to hear it from you!<br />
          Send us a message and we'll respond as soon as possible!
        </div>

        <?= $this->Flash->render(); ?>

        <?= $this->Form->create("Contact",array("url"=>"/contact","class"=>"contact-form","id"=>"contact-form")); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->control("name",array("placeholder"=>"Your Name","label"=>false,"class"=>"form-control")); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->control("email",array("placeholder"=>"Your Email","label"=>false,"class"=>"form-control")); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->control("subject",array("placeholder"=>"The Subject","label"=>false,"class"=>"form-control")); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->textarea("message",array("placeholder"=>"Your Message","label"=>false,"class"=>"form-control")); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->button('Submit',array("class"=>"btn")); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>Social Media</h4>
        <div style="padding-bottom:25px;">
          We are active on a variety of of social media, feel free to like and follow us!
        </div>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook social-media-icon"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-discord social-media-icon"></i></a>
        <?= $this->Form->errors; ?>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

src/Controller/ContactController.php:

```
<?php
  namespace App\Controller;

  use App\Controller\AppController;
  use App\Form\ContactForm;

  class ContactController extends AppController {
    public function add() {
      $contact = new ContactForm();
      if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($contact->execute($this->request->getData())) {
          $this->Flash->success('We will get back to you asap!');
          $this->redirect($this->referer());
        } else {
          $this->Flash->error('There was an issue sending your mail. Please try again later!');
          $this->redirect($this->referer());
        }
      }
      $this->set('contact', $contact);
    }
  }
```

src/Form/ContactForm.php:

```
<?php
  namespace App\Controller;

  use App\Controller\AppController;
  use App\Form\ContactForm;

  class ContactController extends AppController {
    public function add() {
      $contact = new ContactForm();
      if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($contact->execute($this->request->getData())) {
          $this->Flash->success('We will get back to you asap!');
          $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Pages','action' => 'display','contact'));
        } else {
          $this->Flash->error('There was an issue sending your mail. Please try again later!');
          $this->redirect($this->referer());
        }
      }
      $this->set('contact', $contact);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't redirect, because you don't need to. Instead of using the Pages controller to display the form put the form in your controllers view: `/Contacts/add.ctp`. No need to call `redirect()` then.

The errors are already added to the form and the form helper will find them because you're passing the form object to Form->create().

If you want to make it more complicated than needed stick to your implementation and simply write the errors to the session and in the action that receives it read them from the session and set them to the form object via `setErrors()`.

Comment: Where should I create the `/Contact/add.ctp`? my guess would be `src/View/Contact/add.ctp`?

Comment: Oh, removing the redirect showed me where I had to put it (`src/Template/Contact/add.ctp`) :)

Comment: So I moved the form to `src/Template/Contact/add.ctp` and included it into my contact page (`src/Template/Pages/contact.ctp`) using `<?= $this->render('/Contact/add','ajax'); ?>`, but now it won't properly POST the form anymore (no Flash, no mail no nothing but a page refresh and the browser trying to send the POST data).

Comment: I wrote `Instead of using the Pages controller`. You don't need the pages controller at all. Also from what you write makes it pretty obvious that you haven't done or haven't understood the basics of the framework. I highly recommend you to do the tutorial series in the manual to get at least a basic understanding of how the framework works. Without that you'll have a hard time getting anything done right and quick. Go to /contacts/add instead of /pages/add and it will render the page if on GET and POST if everything was done right.

Comment: I have followed the entire CMS tutorial, but I didn't get anything out of it since I couldn't translate the knowledge I found there into the knowledge I need for this specific problem/project...

Comment: One of my old co-workers came by my house today and helped me further. In the end, we went with the way you described it. (the issue was more an issue with me naming stuff wrong and thus getting stuff mixed up). thanks anyways

Comment: Glad to hear that. :) It's not always easy to describe a problem or solution in text, sometimes just asking a work mate solves it in a minute. You can try that as well https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging works for me when nobody to ask is around.

Comment: I already use rdd every now and then (tho with a pluche turtle, not a rubber duck), but it doesn't always work for me :p